# How can I select two fields from two different tables in a Django join?

Tags: sql, django, join, foreign-key-relationship

Suppose I have the following very simple tree structure represented by nodes in a table:

```
class Nodes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    flags = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

What I'd like to know is, how can I emulate the following SQL statement in Django?

```
SELECT parent.name, child.name
FROM Nodes as child
JOIN Nodes as parent ON child.parent == parent.id
WHERE parent.flags == 'STRING1' AND child.flags == 'STRING2';
```

The closest I've gotten seems very inefficient:

```
for parent in Nodes.objects.filter(flags='STRING1'):
    for child in Nodes.objects.filter(flags='STRING2', parent=parent.id):
        print parent.name, child.name
```

Can someone help me understand if there's a better way to execute this SQL query?

Thanks,
- B

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for node in Nodes.objects.filter(flags='STRING2', parent__flags='STRING1'):
    print node.parent.name, node.name
```